# Is it possible to use a fragment with a navigation draw and display the icon in the actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Android Studio 0.8.10

I am wondering is it possible to be a icon in the actionbar for the navigation draw when you are 
using a Fragment to display the ActionBar. I know you can do this from the activity, but I want to do
it from my Fragment. I can display the navigation draw that comes out of the left. But I can't put the icon
in the actionbar.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

This is what I have for my navigation draw layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dlMenus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ssd.fott.FragmentDraw">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundlist"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDetailImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="Picture of newsfeed"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/background">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_large"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:text="@string/fott_feed"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my Fragment class I have the following:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detailfott, container, false);

        mTvDescription = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        mIvDetailImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivDetailImage);
        mTvSubject = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);

        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mNewsFeedDB.get(mId).getImage());
        mIvDetailImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        mTvDescription.setText(mNewsFeedDB.get(mId).getDescription());
        mTvSubject.setText(mNewsFeedDB.get(mId).getSubject());

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                  
                mDrawerLayout,        
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
                R.string.drawer_open,  
                R.string.drawer_close  
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to change your `ActionBar` icon from your `Fragment`?

Comment: I would like to put the navigation drawer icon on there, not sure if that is possible from a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. From inside your `Fragment` `onCreateView()` method, call:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.yourDrawable);
```

Alternatively, you can give a `Drawable` object as parameter to the `setIcon()` method.

For the support version you can use `getSupportActionBar()` instead to access the `Activity` `ActionBar`.